# Php preg_match regexp Как найти подстроку -ссылку на картинку

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, replace, match

Ищу содержимое атрибута src .
Помогите найти, подобрать регулярку

```
$text ='><img alt="" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/6cr1cjzDRtA3jjHDYRCZJtZQ4lj06tZgKivwOG_lFAXAE0hoYcQLUYu1iR3cEg7e3fE-qq1lmT6Ie-oD1Ew4M6jtI5qLQo3GhXW14oY9FwUZqDGyxFKgo1re2Yb4fOAlUGPD1Nw" style="width: 458.00px';

$txt = preg_match("< *img[^>]*src *= *[\"\']?([^\"\']*)", $text, $matches);
```

содержится множество ссылок, потом нужно будет их заменит на свои.
СПАСИБО

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Попробуйте таким образом:

```
$str = '><img alt="" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/6cr1cjzDRtA3jjHDYRCZJtZQ4lj06tZgKivwOG_lFAXAE0hoYcQLUYu1iR3cEg7e3fE-qq1lmT6Ie-oD1Ew4M6jtI5qLQo3GhXW14oY9FwUZqDGyxFKgo1re2Yb4fOAlUGPD1Nw" style="width: 458.00px';

preg_match_all('~(?<=src=")[^"]+(?=")~', $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. 
Можете посоветовать что изучить чтобы разбираться в таких задача?

статьи, книги?

Comment: @user293533 читайте книгу "Регулярные выражения" Джеффри Фридла.

Comment: `src="(.*?)"`  как более понятный вариант

Comment: @teran мне не нравится вариант с подмасками, т.к. в массиве создаются дополнительные элементы, поэтому использую _просмотры_ - они одновременно и проверяют вхождение в подстроку, и не захватывают лишние подстроки в результирующий массив.

Comment: @Эдуард а что из них эффективнее? это более весомый критерий может быть

Comment: @teran по числу итераций в регулярном выражении, подмаски конечно  эффективней, чем просмотры, но они _(подмаски)_ требуют больше памяти. Лично я склоняюсь к мнению, что если есть такой инструмент, и он подходит для решения, то можно его использовать.

Comment: @Эдуард спасибо большое, можете подсказать как вытянуть через регулярку текст из тега <p>  у которого есть класс title - строка выглядит так : 

<p id="h.r6ksg6eob90s" class="c3 title"><span class="c5">Надежды и страхи</span></p>

Comment: @user293533 [смотреть пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c61816b59807e2521f72cff66dde811b89888a9c)

Comment: @Эдуард никак не находит со строкой, а класс c* может быть любым c0-c9 =( p><p class="c5 title" id="h.r6ksg6eob90s"><span class="c3">&#1053;&#1072;&#1076;&#1077;&#1078;&#1076;&#1099; &#1080; &#1089;&#1090;&#1088;&#1072;&#1093;&#1080;</span></p><xz dwqd

Comment: @user293533, по ссылке из моего предыдущего комментария скрипт находит именно то, что было написано вами в комментарии выше, и чтобы в этом убедиться, нужно кликнуть по кнопке Execute code.

Comment: @Эдуард для чего нужна лямбда и s ? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ec6de8b41a6bde1cf6056aec354368dc9d1b738

Comment: @Эдуард спасибо большое, кажется получилось

Comment: @user293533  в параметр лямбда - функции попадает подстрока, соответствующая шаблону, переданному первым параметром в коллбэк.